# When and how is this function being called in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout, promise

I'm working through [this](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/design/README.js) tutorial on implementing a promise library with JavaScript.  I'm fairly new to JavaScript, but I have an extensive Java background.

I came across the following code that is confusing me.

```
var maybeOneOneSecondLater = function() {
    var callback;
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback("hello, there");
    }, 1000);
    return {
        then: function(_callback) {
            callback = _callback;
        }
    };
};
```

Consider I make the following call.

```
maybeOneOneSecondLater();
```

It seems like setTimeout should be called.  Nothing happens, and callback is obviously undefined at this point.

But when I make the following call:

```
maybeOneOneSecondLater().then(function(message){
     alert(message);
});
```

The variable callback is assigned, and the setTimeout method executes the callback.  I get the alert displaying the message "hello, there".

I don't really know what to Google to answer this question.  It appears to me that something is "watching", for lack of a better term, the callback variable, and once it is assigned it executes the code.

Would someone explain to me what is happening here?  Thank you!

**UPDATE** What I was missing was the one second lapse before setTimeout's callback is called.  Thank you all for the great answers.  There was no magic involved after all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `maybeOneOneSecondLater()` is called, its `var callback` is bound to the 2 places where it appears in its body: in the anonymous function passed to `SetTimeout` and in the "not so anonymous function" which is the `then` member of the object it returns. These bindings are the "closure", which survives the function call.

This:

```
maybeOneOneSecondLater().then(function(message){
   alert(message);
});
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var x = maybeOneOneSecondLater();
var y = function(message){
   alert(message);
};
x.then(y);
```

If the first and the second line were separated by code which would allow the 1 sec timeout to cick in, JavaScript would be left with the unassigned `callback` variable, which it cannot interpret as a function that can be called with the `"hello world"` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand:

`maybeOneOneSecondLater` returns an object with a function called `then` that accepts a callback as parameter and assigns it to the variable `callback` that was set to be called after 1 second

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is watching it.

1 second after `maybeOneOneSecondLater()` is called, the function passed to `setTimeout` is called (that's what `setTimeout` does).

It takes less than 1 second for `.then(function(message){alert(message);});` to run and cause something to be assigned to `callback`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is "watching" it, its value is being changed. Here, try this:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++) setTimeout(function() {alert(i);},i*1000);
```

You would expect to get 0, then 1, 2, 3, and 4 in separate alerts, right? Wrong. You get 5 alerted in each one.

This is because the value has changed.

Comment: And because the inner function continues to have access to the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function within a function creates a closure. The inner function continues to have access to the outer variables.

Since the setTimeout does not execute immediately upon invocation of `maybeOneOneSecondLater`, there is still time for `then()` to assign the callback before the time expires.